# How to navigate between views in Vaadin v8?

Tags: view, navigation, vaadin, vaadin8

Can some let me know why I am receiving a NullPointerException when we try to navigate from Login to HomePage.

The Login Page is which has a NavigaeTO method pointing towards HomePage is below

```
public class MyUI extends UI implements View {

    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout vlayout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name1 = new TextField();
        name1.setCaption("Username");


        final TextField name2 = new TextField();
        name2.setCaption("Password");


        final HorizontalLayout hlaylout1 = new HorizontalLayout();
        Button button1 = new Button("Login",
        new Button.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

                System.out.print("Here is the View String "+NavigatorUI.HOMEVIEW);

             getNavigator().navigateTo(NavigatorUI.HOMEVIEW);
            }
        });
        Button button2 = new Button("Cancel");

        hlaylout1.addComponents(button1, button2);



        vlayout.addComponents(name1,name2, hlaylout1);

        setContent(vlayout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

The Home Page is which should open when the Login button is clicked is

```
public class HomeView extends UI implements View {

    Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout vlayout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name1 = new TextField();
        name1.setCaption("HomePage");           


        vlayout.addComponents(name1);

        setContent(vlayout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

And the Navigator class is

```
public class NavigatorUI extends UI {

    Navigator navigator;
    public static final String HOMEVIEW = "HOMEVIEW";

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        getPage().setTitle("Navigation Example");

        // Create a navigator to control the views  
        navigator = new Navigator(this, this);

        // Create and register the views
        navigator.addView(HOMEVIEW, new HomeView());
        navigator.addView("", new MyUI());
 //       navigator.addView(MAINVIEW, new MainView());

}

}
```

I am receiving the NullPointerException for the NavigateTo method. Can someone let me know what the issue is?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues in your code:

- You define multiple servlets, one is enough
- All your views extend UI, only the `NavigatorUI` should extend UI, the others can build the layouts in the constructor
- Your servlet is configured to use `MyUI`, but it should be `NavigatorUI` for that UI to be used
- You should override `getNavigator()` in `NavigatorUI` to return your newly created navigator, or call `setNavigator(navigator)`.
- You should remove the `Navigator navigator` field from your views.